# I want to save sticky notes without save buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

```html
   <div class="block-update-card status" ng-show="isShow">
    <div class="update-card-body">
      <div class="update-card-body">

      <p><textarea name="feedback"   spellcheck="false" placeholder="Discription" ></textarea></p>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action-pellet btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group fa fa-mail-reply"></div>
  <div class="btn-group fa fa-bell"></div>
  <div class="btn-group fa fa-trash"></div>
  <div class="btn-group fa fa-photo"></div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

am working on sticky project i want to know how the sticky save without save button

Comment: Use enter event and try, will work.

Comment: blur event, change event, keyup event, timeout ... 4 ways I can think of without having a save button

Comment: this all event will take continues request

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite unclear, but I'm guessing you want to save an input (on a sticky note) without having to click on a save button.

You can either put some events on the keyboard (save when "Enter" is pressed, for example) : Here is a [link](https://richardcooke.info/trigger-a-button-click-when-pressing-enter-in-a-textbox-in-angularjs/) to do it

or put a $watcher on the input and save it whenever it's changed (with a good delay to avoid doing too many api calls)

```
scope.$watch('yourInput', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // save function with the newValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution here is to use a timer to automatically save.  There are several strategies.

1. **Interval Timer to look for changes.**  Set an interval timer (say for every 15 seconds).  If the note has been changed since the last time you saved, then do another save.  If not, just wait for the next timer to fire.  This requires you to keep track of when the note is changed after each save which there are several strategies for.  The simplest might be to extract the text and just save the text from the last saved version.  If the text is different, then save it and update the saved text.
2. **Set auto-save timer when document modified.**  Each time the note is modified (you will have to register an event handler for changes), you save the note, but if the last save was less than NN seconds ago, you set a timer that will fire NN seconds from the last save.  If a timer is already scheduled, you don't set another one, you just let that one take care of the auto-save for you.   This has the advantage that no timer is running all the time as in option 1.
3. **Use timer to detect when user has paused typing and auto-save then.**  When you detect the note has been changed, you set a short timer (like 5 seconds from now).  If the user types before the timer fires, you cancel that timer and set a new timer for 5 seconds from now.   Whenever the timer fires, you autosave.  The idea is that you start looking for a pause in typing when the user first modifies the note.  As long as they keep typing, you keep postponing when you'll do the autosave.  As soon as they pause at least N seconds from typing, you autosave.